# How do I set up a container without a subdomain using nginx-proxy?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I have several services running in Docker containers, all behind an an Nginx reverse proxy (using [`nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy`](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy)). All of the services run on different subdomains, and they are all working correctly with HTTPS etc.

I am now trying to host another container that uses Nginx to serve a static Web site on the domain itself, without a subdomain, but I am struggling to get it to work.

Here is my minimal `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  example:
     image: nginx 
     expose:
       - 80
       - 443
     restart: unless-stopped
     environment:
       VIRTUAL_HOST: domain.tld
       LETSENCRYPT_HOST: domain.tld
     container_name: example
     volumes:
       - ./content:/usr/share/nginx/html

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

This does not work: it shows a 500 Internal Server Error whether I try to access it through HTTP or HTTPS. If I do the exact same thing but using `subdomain.domain.tld` for the `VIRTUAL_HOST` and `LETSENCRYPT_HOST` environment variables, it works fine for both.

If I add the following to the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
    ports:
      - "8003:80"
      - "8443:443"
```

...then I can access the site at `http://domain.tld:8003`, but `https://domain.tld:8443` shows a failure to connect and `https://domain.tld` still shows a 500 error. `http://domain.tld` redirects to `https://domain.tld`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had AAAA records for the root domain, but not the subdomains, and I was using `nginx-proxy/acme-companion` to automatically generate my SSL certificates.

The `nginx-proxy/acme-companion` documentation states the following under the [‘Requirements’](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/acme-companion#requirements) heading:

> If your (sub)domains have AAAA records set, the host must be publicly reachable over IPv6 on port 80 and 443.

So, per the [`nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy` documentation](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy#ipv6-support), to enable IPv6:

> You can activate the IPv6 support for the nginx-proxy container by passing the value true to the `ENABLE_IPV6 environment variable:
>
> `docker run -d -p 80:80 -e ENABLE_IPV6=true -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro nginxproxy/nginx`

My final `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
   example:
     image: nginx 
     expose:
       - 80
       - 443
     restart: unless-stopped
     environment:
       VIRTUAL_HOST: domain.tld,www.domain.tld
       LETSENCRYPT_HOST: domain.tld,www.domain.tld
     container_name: example
     volumes:
       - ./content:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
       - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```